# Overloading method with different parameterized type parameter

Tags: java, overloading, generic-method

`List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` are different type: if that is the case why overloading the following method does not compile?

```
public static  void iMethod(List<Number> nList){
    System.out.println(nList);
}
```

```
public static  void iMethod(List<Integer> iList){
    System.out.println(iList);
}
```

error:

> Erasure of iMethod<List<integer>> is same as another method in class

Comment: Since Java suffers from "generic type erasure", don't you think the two methods will look exactly the same after compiling?

Comment: Both iList and nList in the method parameter is object reference of List Type.

Comment: I am studying generics, i understand that Type parameter `T` will be erased but note sure  if we specify the type like `integer`, it will do the same.

Comment: List will receive `Integer` as its generic type `T`. So yes, both gets erased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has this thing called "type erasure" which causes problems like this when compiling generic code like this. When compiled, `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` are both just plain `List`.

Comment: I understand that Type parameter `T` will be erased but not sure if we specify the type like `Integer`, it will do the same.

Comment: what do you mean *just plain List*

Comment: As far as the JVM is concerned, generics don't really exist. It's kind of a bolted-on syntactical thing. At the byte code level, the only thing that exists is List. List<Integer>, Set<T>, Map<String, String> all go through type erasure and become List, Set and Map, respectively.

Comment: *thing that exists is List.* you mean `List<Object>`?

Comment: No, I mean unparameterized List. At least conceptually. In the actual implementation I have installed, it's actually specified as List<E>, because the old, unparameterized List class (that, yes, took Object elements) doesn't seem to exist any more. But conceptually it's still in there.

Comment: But if you try to cast it, it won't let you :D : `incompatible types: Map<String, Object> cannot be converted to Map<Custom, Object>`

Answer (score 2):

All your generic code
is strictly for the compiler. Through a process called "type erasure," the compiler
does all of its verifications on your generic code and then strips the type information
out of the class bytecode.

In other words, even
though you WROTE

```
List < Integer > myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

By the time the compiler is done with it, the JVM sees what it always saw before
Java 5 and generics:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```